# Calling a mouse dobleclick on a windowsformhost(wpf) of a usercontrol(winforms)

Tags: wpf, vb.net, user-controls, windowsformshost

Im creating a wpf application but i cant seem to work the events of the user control 
in the mainwindow.axml i create a windowsformhost and i load perfectly the content(load data of a dataset, etc...) when running ,but how can i handle the events of a mouse or keydown i try this.

in the user control:

```
Public Event DOBLECLICK()
Public Sub sp1_CellDoubleClick(sender As Object, e As 
    FarPoint.Win.Spread.CellClickEventArgs) Handles sp1.CellDoubleClick
    RaiseEvent DOBLECLICK()
End Sub
```

in the mainwindow:
i try to load the event but not seem to respond.

```
Private Sub WinFormsHost_MouseLeftButtonUp(sender As Object, e As 
    MouseButtonEventArgs) Handles WinFormsHost.MouseLeftButtonUp

    AddHandler host.sp1.CellDoubleClick, AddressOf host.sp1_CellDoubleClick

End Sub


Private Sub Control_MouseDoubleClick_1(sender As Object, e As MouseEventArgs)
    AddHandler host.sp1.CellDoubleClick, AddressOf host.sp1_CellDoubleClick
End Sub
```

Comment: You should only declare the handler in your main function once.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In `MainWindow_Loaded`function, add this:

```
AddHandler host.sp1.CellDoubleClick, AddressOf host.sp1_CellDoubleClick
```

Then create a new function in your class (It gets called when you doubleclick on a cell. Don't use `Handles` after this because you already added the handler in your `MainWindow_Loaded`):

```
Public Sub sp1_CellDoubleClick(sender As Object, e As FarPoint.Win.Spread.CellClickEventArgs)
    RaiseEvent DOBLECLICK()
End Sub
```

Functions `WinFormsHost_MouseLeftButtonUp` and `Control_MouseDoubleClick_1` are not needed. You can remove them.

Comment: i dont have a function, or i dont seem to undestand can you please make and example?

Comment: @ManuelMedina, could you please elaborate? What function do you mean?

Comment: I'm assuming you're talking about the main function. Do you have something like `Form_Load` ?

Comment: do i have to write te event handler there? if there is , how do i do it?

Comment: @ManuelMedina, I've updated my answer so that you could hopefully understand it better.

Comment: thanks a lot, now i dont have the error, but how can i work whit it in wpf for example, hide the winformhost i know i cant hide whit WinFormsHost.Visibility = Windows.Visibility.Hidden but when double clicked do this WinFormsHost.Visibility = Windows.Visibility.Hidden

Comment: I'm sorry. I can't quite understand your question and would kindly ask you to open another question or search because that question you asked has nothing to do with the original one. Also if my answer helped you, please be so kind to accept it as your solution by clicking the check mark on it. :)